# JS targeting nested divs which contain video

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to target a video element nested inside a div which has an id that I can set plus another div which has no id. What would be a smooth approach to targeting the video element and simply playing the video.

here is a sample of the nesting i am looking at.

```
<div id="vid1">
    <div>
        <video poster="poster_img.png" >
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Would you recommend `childNodes`, `querySelector` or another thing?

Using JS I want to be able to say, `vid1.play();`
but these have all failed

```
document.getElementById('vid_1').childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('video');
document.getElementById('vid_1').childNodes[0].querySelector('video');
```

Comment: Use jQuery, it does all things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`document.querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with `PARENT CHILD` selector

Also note you had typo in `vid_1`, in markup it is **`vid1`**

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#vid1 video'));
//---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```html
<div id="vid1">
  <div>
    <video poster="poster_img.png">
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh geez, thanks! perfect answer. I just need to figure out how to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @conflictingresults — How to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)  :) __Happy coding!__